# How can delete Ajax Request from browser memory?

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory, mootools

I have a simple problem, how can I delete the ajax request store into the memory. I'll try to explain what I'm will trying to get.

I have a form for edit a table into database.

All runs well the first time, but the problem is after trying again. If I don't refresh the page, it always sent the same data from the first request.

Example:

Into database I have

```
id
user
password
```

I have a form with the same parameters, and I called this form with ajax.

I edited a register from the database, and I sent the data edited, and run well, but into the browser memory, the request is stored.

I try to edit again the same register, but when I send again, the data is the same like the first time.

If the first time send:

```
user : 'userx'
password : 'usex1234'
```

When I try again to edit this register for example with:

```
user: 'userxx'
password : 'password1234'
```

at the end, the data send has these values

```
user : 'userx'
password : 'usex1234'
```

How can fix this? I suppose delete the first request, but I can't.
I want to clean the memory from browser without f5 or refreshing, because only with f5, running again well.

I tried:

`request = new Request();`

`request = null;` but not happens nothing

`delete request;` but is the same, nothing changes.

Who can help me please?

MY CODE:

---

```
function _update(id){
    var n = Number(new Date());
    var edit = new Request({
        url: 'users/edit?'+new Date().getTime(),
        noCache: true,
        onRequest: function(){
            $('dark').setStyle('display','block');
        },
        onSuccess: function(data){
            $('dark').setStyle('display','none');
            box_edit.close();
            update();
        },
        onComplete: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        onFailure: function(){
            Sexy.error("Ocurrio un error procesando su solicitud, intente más tarde.");
        }   
});

var box_edit = new LightFace.Request({
    url: 'users/edit?'+new Date().getTime(),
    draggable:true,
    title: 'Editar usuario.',
    request:{
        method: 'post',
        data: { isc_user_id: id }
    },
    buttons: [ { title: 'Editar', color:'blue', event: function(){
    var id__ = $('isc_user_frm_id_'+id).get('value');
            if (before_update(id__)){
                if ( $('isc_password_'+id__).get('value')=='' && $('isc_re-password_'+id__).get('value')==''){
                    var data = 'userEdit=Ok&isc_user='+$('isc_user_'+id__).get('value')+'&isc_group='+$('isc_group_'+id__).getSelected().get('name')+'&isc_user_id='+ id;
                }else{
                    var data = 'userEdit=Ok&isc_user='+$('isc_user_'+id__).get('value')+'&isc_password='+hex_md5($('isc_password_'+id__).get('value'))+'&isc_group='+$('isc_group_'+id__).getSelected().get('name')+'&isc_user_id='+ id;
                }
                edit.send(data);
            }
        } 
    },
    { title:'Cancelar', event:function(){ this.close(); } }]
});
box_edit.open();}
```

Comment: `data: { isc_user_id: id }` i might be getting this wrong, but it seems to me that you have already set the data here, so when you send  the data it is always the same data sent.

Comment: ibrahim this id, it's only for get the user row data. i have a list with all records, and this list have the 'id' for edit or erase depends of the purpose, the Request which send the form data to update into the database is  var edit = new Request(...);

Comment: instead of sending the data `edit.send(data)` try to use `alert(data)` to debug and see if you have the correct data in it first

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution, as your server-side should be stateless, and the variables shouldn't be cached to send to the server, so the problem is probably with how you are getting the values.

The browser may cache when it requests information from the server, which is why it was suggested to turn off caching, but that is for data coming from the server.

So, I would suggest you use the Firebug extension on Firefox and you can put in breakpoints to see if the values are changing.

For every part of setting data you should put these in variables so you can check each value easily.

I didn't create all the variables, but I wanted to show an example to help you.

```
var val1 = $('isc_user_'+id__).get('value');
var val2 = $('isc_password_'+id__).get('value');
var data = 'userEdit=Ok&isc_user='+$('isc_user_'+id__).get('value')+'&isc_password='+hex_md5($('isc_password_'+id__).get('value'))+'&isc_group='+$('isc_group_'+id__).getSelected().get('name')+'&isc_user_id='+ id;
```

You will also want to look at the value of `id` as you may not be appropriately changing that value when the password is changed.  I expect this will be your problem.

Comment: i try this, but always the variables gets the results from the first request

Comment: @Paridin - So this problem is not an ajax problem.  Is the id value changing?  I will expect it isn't, which will probably be the core of your problem.

Comment: yes isn't ajax problem, but in theory i want to delete the request, like if i had a garbage collector, 'cause maybe is a bug into the core, found when show the forms to edit the info with ajax, i suppose it because all forms have the same name, so
the mootools core, gets the values from the first form all time so with this base i create a dinamically names, and mootools got always, the first data of the form but now the form is unique so i got it.

Answer (score 0):

Append a string like e.g. a timestamp to the requested url, this prevents the browser from using the cached version of the requested ressource.

In mootools there is a noCache-option for Request, set it to true.(default is false, so the cache will be used there without setting the option)

Comment: That wouldn't help the user solve the problem as described, since they're already changing the value of `password`

Comment: like this? 
var r = Number(new Date());
url : 'file.php?'+r,
i try this but nothing happens.

Comment: `'file.php?'+new Date().getTime();` (you'll have to append a new timestamp on every request), but using the noCache-option will do the same.

Comment: i have noCache like false, i try 'file.php?'+new Date().getTime(); but i have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> ---
>
> FIX
>
> ---
>
> Ok, after tring a lot of ways to fix, I found a solution, which consist of creating a dynamic form. I created a random variable and sent just before to get the form with ajax, after  recovery this value into the server code, I put this value like a name of the form and I have a dynamic form. With this I fixed the problem.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> function rand(){
>     return Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
> }
>
>
> function _update(id){
> var form_rand = rand();
> ...
> data: { isc_user_id: id , form_rand : form_rand }
> ...
> ```
>
> To get the value now:
>
> ```
> var id__ = $('isc_user_frm_id_'+id+form_rand).get('value');
> ```
>
> Into the html I have and hidden input like this:
>
> ```
> <input type="hidden" id="isc_user_frm_id_<?php echo $form_rand; ?>" value="<?php echo $r; ?>" ?>
> ```

Comment: ([Question was answered in an edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)